# Text File processing and Grouping the records using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a text file with n number of records and each records contains three columns with delimited by tab. I am reading this text file and performing some mapping on the second column using the Powershell scripting. Once I am done with the mapping, I need to group the records if the column 1 and column 2 are equal.

**Input File:**

col1 col2    data

4803 6000000 10.00

4802 6000000 20.00

4803 6000000 20.00

4803 5000000 30.00

**Output after the mapping:**

4803 5000000 10.00

4802 6000000 20.00

4803 5000000 20.00

4803 5000000 30.00

**Expected Result:** Need to group the records based on column 1 and column 2

4803 5000000 60.00

4802 6000000 60.00

**Powershell Script:**

```
$fields = Get-Content Temp.txt
$results = @()
foreach($i in $fields)
{
$field  = $i -split '\t' -replace '^\s*|\s*$'
$field1 = $field[0]
$field2 = $field[1]
$field3 = $field[2]

if ($field1 -eq "4803" -and $field[2].substring(0,2) -eq "60")
    {
        $field2 = "5000000"
    }
else
    {
        $field2 = $field[1]
    }
        $details = @{       
                Column1     = $field1
                Column2     = $field2
                Column3     = $field3
            }
    $results += New-Object PSObject -Property $details 
}
$results | ForEach-Object { '{0}    {1} {2}' -f $_.Column1,$_.Column1, $_.Column2,| Set-Content -path Temp.txt    [Environment]::Exit(0)
```

Comment: We have the expected result but what is the script currently generating and how does it differ from the expected result?  however this would be MUCH easier if you just used `Import-CSV -Delimiter Tab` instead of the get-content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do it. I just use Import-Csv to read the tab delimited file, and then grouped on the first two fields and summed the data. I then wrote it back out in the same format.

```
$data = Import-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -Path C:\path\to\file\data.txt
$grp = $data | Group-Object -Property {$_.col1 + "|" + $_.col2 } 
$dat = $grp | %{ New-Object psobject -Property @{ Item=$_.Name; Sum = ($_.Group | Measure-object data -Sum).Sum }} 
$dat | %{ $f = $_.Item.Split('|'); "{0} {1} {2,2:n}" -f ($f[0],$f[1],$_.Sum) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I got (which I incorporate the advise of Mike Garuccio). I don't know how you get the 60 for 4802. I assumed it is a typo, since it is not a SUM.

```
$rows = Import-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -Path ".\Temp.txt"

foreach($row in $rows) {
    if ($row.col1 -eq "4803" -and $row.col2.substring(0,2) -eq "60") {
        $row.col2 = "5000000"
    }
    echo $row.col1, "`t", $row.col2
}

$groupedRows = $rows | group col1, col2

$groupedRows | foreach {
    [pscustomobject] @{
        col1 = $_.group | select -unique -expand col1
        col2 = $_.group | select -unique -expand col2
        'Sum' = ($_.group | measure data -sum).sum
    }
}
```